# JQuery- Change the id of an element and call a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element with some id, I changed its `ID` and when I click on that element (with new `ID` now), it still calls the function with previous `ID`

```js
$('#1st').click(function(){
    $('#1st').attr('id','2nd');
    alert("id changed to 2nd");
});
$('#2nd').click(function(){
    alert("clicked on second");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="1st">Click</a>
```

Example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/25n4y64e/)

Comment: always post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I can't open the link...

Comment: It's easy: http://jsfiddle.net/9zx581td/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you add the event before the element exists. It does not find an element. Either attach the event when you change the id or you need to use event delegation.

```js
    $('#1st').on("click.one", function(e) {
      $('#1st').attr('id', '2nd');
      alert("id changed to 2nd");
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).off("click.one");
    });
    $(document).on("click", '#2nd', function() {
      alert("clicked on second");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="1st">Click</a>
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra qork when he could just use better delegation as proposed by fermis

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/25n4y64e/2/)

```js
    $(document).on('click', '#2nd', function(){
  alert("clicked on second");
 })
 .on('click', '#1st', function(e) {
  $('#1st').attr('id','2nd');
  alert("id changed to 2nd");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="1st">Click</a>
```

Also see this post on using [**Jquery's .on() versus .click()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)